# How to import cocos2dx project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I have a problem and want to help from you . I get some Cocos2dx source code I want to publish on the play store

I want someone to show me how to add Cocos2dx on eclipse on a Windows machine

so I will be able to publish those code .Please anyone able to tell me step by step what should i do ..

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096191/cant-link-to-cocos2dx-using-eclipse-for-android-on-osx?rq=1

Comment: Sir i have search these link but didnt found the exact solution . Please help me out .

Comment: You've tried those links, but you're not telling us which steps you've successfully done, nor which steps you're currently stuck on. In other words, you really haven't told us anything, but you still want us to write an exhaustive detailed step-by-step guide of what you have to do. Are you really being serious? Really? We are just unpaid volunteers answering questions. If you're not willing to put any effort into this, there is no reason any of us should put effort into answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hello friend i am also working on cocos2dx .. and i have done setup correctly and its working for me ... i am going to describe what i have done........it may help for you as well as others



=============cocos2dx android setup guide=====================================

-  check for these 6 things
   1-> adt
   2-> ndk
   3-> cocos2dx
   4-> Python 
   5-> cygwin (setup-x86_64)
   6-> jdk

// now do all steps one by one

1-> first create a specific folder where you want to setup android 
2-> copy all these files (which mentioned above) 
3-> extract adt
4-> extract ndk
5-> extract cocos2dx
6-> install python 
7-> install cygwin  (to install this you need internet connection ..so follow the steps under -- how to install cygwin)
8-> setup environment variable for cygwin -----
                  -to set this open environment variable which you find mycomputer->properties->advance settings->environment variable
                  - now find path variable and add the path of cygwin ex-- mine ic c:/cygwin64/bin
                  - add another variable for ndk   NDK_ROOT ->  mine is F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\android-ndk-r10d

9 -> check for java (jdk) for eclipse , if not then install java
10-> set environment variable -> edit path ---add path for java ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;
  at start of this path
 11->you have done android setup ;




 how to install cygbin
 =============================

 -> double click on cygbin file->click next->next->next->next->next-
 -> now select mirror any one i choose http://cygbin.mirror.constant.com
 -> click next
 -> now u got select package -> search for the following one by one
       autoconf, automake, binutils, gcc-core, gcc-g**, gcc4-core, gcc4-g**, gdb, pcre, pcre-devel, gawk, make


       neccesory packages--->   make 

       ->and follow the instructions


======================================     
    finally ... you have done with setup now open elipse
    import your project -race track->proj.android
    import libcocos2dx--->   CoCos2Dx\cocos2dx\platform\android\java

now open cygbin.bat file-> go to you project resourse directory -> run command --   chmod -R 777 *  
    clean your project and run








==============================================================================================================
    CREATE NEW PROJECT IN COCOS2DX BY COMMAND PROMPT
==============================================================================================================  


    1-> open cmd
    2-> 

    go to path--CoCos2Dx\tools\project-creator   ( MINE WAS F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\tools\project-creator)
      now typing   cd above path  then press enter 
      now type f:  press enter
 3-> type command   create_project.py -project MyGame -package com.sensiblemobiles.mygame -language cpp
 then press enter

 4-> you have done with this. a project is created in cocos2dx/projects  folder
 5-> now to add this project in adt follow istruction (HOWW TO ADD COCOS2DX PROJECT IN ADT






=============================================================================================================== 
                        HOW TO ADD COCOS2DX PROJECT IN ADT
==============================================================================================================

follow thest steps to import a cocos2dx project for android in adt eclipse



1->  open eclipse go to file->import->Existing android code into workspace (under android tab) ->click next-> click on Browse
2-> Go to your project root folder like MyGame->proj.android
3-> finish  , your project will be added into project explorer


4-> to enable cocos2dx you need to import libcocos2dx follow above instruction same and go to root directory by following below path

 ->  CoCos2Dx\cocos2dx\platform\android\java    (F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\cocos2dx\platform\android\java)

5-> now add this libcocos2dx in to your project
   -> right click on your project ->properties->click android tab ->  click add button -> select libcocos2dx -> ok -> apply ->ok

6-> Now to see your classes in this project follow below instruction

  -> right click on your project -> properties -> explore resourse tab -> linked resourse -> path variables -> Now click on add (a dialog will be Open)
      - Name   :  COCOS2DX
      - Location : enter path of your cocos2dx   (mine was F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx)
     -   click ok  -> again OK

7-> you need some more steps below

        -> right click on your project -> explore  tab C/c++ General -> select Code Analysis -> select Use Project Setting -> now uncheck Syntax and Symantic errors -> apply -> ok 

8-> Add path of cocosdension

 again go to your project -> right click -> explore  tab C/c++ General -> Path and Symbol -> selsect Include Tab -> select GNU++ -> click on Add button 
        -> fill dialog box  paste path of cocos2dx/cocosdension / include   (mine was F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\CocosDenshion\include)        
        - press ok -> apply -> ok 

9->Now go to Project Tab of adt -> clean your project

10-> finally you have done 



=============================================================================================================================
     NOW MAKE FEW CHANGES TO YOUR ANDROID.MK FILE
=============================================================================================================================
EXPLORE YOUR PROJECT -> JNI -> ANDROID.MK

 NOTE :  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

            BELOW THE ABOVE LINES YOU HAVE TO ADD ALL CPP FILES LIKE ABOVE WITHOUT ANY SPACES 



===============================================================================================================================
         ENABLE BOX 2D IF YOU WANT TO USE BOX2D
===============================================================================================================================
FOLLOW ALL THE ABOVE STEPS TO CREATE NEW PROJECT AND IMPORT IT IN ADT ECLIPSE ;

NOW FOLLOW SOME MORE STEPS TO ENABLE BOX2D;


1->     right click on your project -> properties -> explore resourse tab -> linked resourse -> path variables -> Now click on add (a dialog will be Open)
      - Name   :  Box2D
      - Location : enter path of your Box2d   (mine was F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\external\Box2D)
     -   click ok  -> again OK   

2->   now include box2d in include  
        again go to your project -> right click -> explore  tab C/c++ General -> Path and Symbol -> selsect Include Tab -> select GNU++ -> click on Add button 
        -> fill dialog box  paste path of \CoCos2Dx\external\Box2D   (mine was F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\external\Box2D)      
        - press ok -> apply -> ok 

3->         now add Box2D source 

            again go to your project -> right click -> explore  tab C/c++ General -> Path and Symbol -> select Source Location Tab -> select Link Folder -> check the chek box
        ->   paste path of \CoCos2Dx\external\Box2D   (mine was F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\external\Box2D)     
        - press ok -> apply -> ok 

4-> change in application.mk file 

    EXPLORE YOUR PROJECT -> JNI -> application.mk
        replace this line (     APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1)
        to -- APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=0 -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -DCC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION=1

Note -> this will enable Box2d and disable chipmunk 
  finaly save this file     

 5->   change in android.mk file 

    EXPLORE YOUR PROJECT -> JNI -> android.mk

      after this line (LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes) with "space" 
        add path of box2d like ($(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../external/Box2D) after the line 

Note -> this will include Box2d  
  finalLy save this file        

 6-> ok you have done with box2d .   clean your project an enjoy... best of luck



 =============================================================================================================================================
 REMEMBER   FEW THINGS 
 ============================================================================================================================================

 1-> ADD NEW CLASS IN CLASSES FOLDER
 2-> ADD ALL RESOURCE INTO RESOURSEC FOLDER
 3-> AFTER ADDING NEW RESOURE REFRESH YOUR ANDROID PROJECT THEN RUN (PERMISSION) COMMAND INTO CYGWIN
       (cygbin.bat file-> go to you project resourse directory -> run command --   chmod -R 777 *   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these links

1. "How to run cpp-tests on Android" :
   http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Android
2. "The Completest Cocos2d-x Tutorial & Guide List" :
   [The Completest Cocos2d-x Tutorial & Guide List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711047/the-completest-cocos2d-x-tutorial-guide-list)
3. "Cocos2D-X Tutorial for iOS and Android: Getting Started" :
   http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

In brief, you will have to

1. Install library for Java JDK
2. Install library for Android SDK&NDK
3. Extract Cocos2dx For Cocos2dx 2.2.x , you may use Cygwin. For
   cocos2dx 3.x, you may use Python and Ant
4. Download and extract Eclipse
5. Installing the Eclipse Plugin for ADT
6. Import android project in Eclipse
7. Try build and run it.

In which step you are?